# LinearLayout not showing all its children

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-cardview

After creating a `LinearLayout` with `ImageView`s as its children, I noticed that only the first row of items are shown. I thought the `LinearLayout` would automatically wrap its children onto a new line as necessary? The width seems fine but not the height.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Expected blueprint (`ImageView` count is not to scale)**

[image]
For some reason, when I create a LinearLayout inside another view, the width is shown correctly, but it never seems to adjust its height to fit & show all the children inside it.

**Current result**

[image]

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv_facilities">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_facilities"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_titlerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_expandcollapsearrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_topicsymbol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_symbols"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_language" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pets" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_c"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_verified_user" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_d"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_transport" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_e"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_seat" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_g"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_areoplane_depart" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_symbol_h"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_areoplane_arrive" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior of `LinearLayout` is "as intended": it will display its children in a horizontal or vertical line.

Since all of the child `View`s in your blueprint seem to be of a similar size, consider switching to `GridLayout`, it is available as androidx-library (e.g. *androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0*).

For child `View`s with varying dimensions, `FlexboxLayout` is a good alternative. It was introduced in a [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) in February 2017. There is a version for androidx available: *'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'*

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal LinearLayout will not automatically wrap to a second line to fit it's children. Per the Android documentation it only supports a single direction:

> LinearLayout is a view group that aligns all children in a single
>   direction, vertically or horizontally

What you could do is use [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) to achieve the wrapping behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Don't make horizontal linearLayout with 6 imageView's

Make new  vertical linearlayout and put on it two horizontal linear layout for each one 3 imageView .